Test a service that uses JDBI using junit 5 and mokito
I started using JDBI instead of JDBC Hibernate. I have it working nicely by passing a query to it. When I run it locally I use mysql database and when I run unit tests I use H2 in-memory database. Then I use liquibase to create the tables and load sample data for mysql and h2 database for both use-cases.
I have a service that uses jdbi and the code works.
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    Jdbi jdbi;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> surveyByGuid(String surveyGuid) {
        try {
            List<Map<String, Object>> tables = jdbi.withHandle(handle ->
                handle.createQuery(SqlQueryConstants.GET_BY_GUID).bind("survey_guid", surveyGuid).mapToMap().list());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(tables, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
            log.error("Exception occurred when getting survey by name {}", e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(e.getRawStatusCode()).body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
    }

}

Now I want to test this service by using liquibase again and connect to H2.
@SpringBootTest(classes = DxSurveyManagementApiApp.class)
class SurveyssServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    Jdbi jdbi;

    @InjectMocks
    SurveyssService surveyssService;

    @Test
    void surveyByNameTest() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> tables = jdbi.withHandle(handle ->
            handle.createQuery(SqlQueryConstants.GET_BY_GUID).bind("survey_guid", "3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8").mapToMap().list());
        System.out.println(tables);
        surveyssService.surveyByGuid("3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8");
    }

}

When I run surveyByNameTest(). jdbi statement runs without issues by connecting to H2 database but jdbi is null from the service. What am I missing?
From the logs I can see liquibase is running and creating the tables and loading the data.
All objects dropped from SA@jdbc:h2:mem:dxsurveymanagement
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::survey_metadata_table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::data-for-survey-metadata-table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::survey_repository_table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::data-for-survey-repository-table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::questions_repository_table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::data-for-questions-repository-table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::options_repository_table::dxSurvey
Running Changeset: config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_survey_schema.xml::data-for-options-repository-table::dxSurvey
Liquibase: Update has been successful. Rows affected: 8

And tables are printed
[{survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=1, question_guid=4c0e37b8-1bfd-431f-8a04-3354108606bc, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=2, question_guid=5de05c9e-4d1c-4099-ba67-ae10e2127bea, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=3, question_guid=ebf997c6-5be6-4a18-abc3-43353c8c3a9b, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=4, question_guid=9ebb9474-0fcf-4098-9317-5ed8d973d830, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=5, question_guid=fd12f831-bf14-47ea-9260-a547380eca22, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=6, question_guid=b4961130-5ab3-46b7-b95a-929fc0cf7807, type=text, choice_order=null, choice_id=, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=7, question_guid=d5862b04-cd56-4a9a-8702-5b78b18390cb, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=8, question_guid=a5e7d2da-708d-468a-ad68-72bdadecd36e, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=8, question_guid=a5e7d2da-708d-468a-ad68-72bdadecd36e, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=9, question_guid=347ece59-be71-463e-bc87-bb80f9c5194e, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=9, question_guid=347ece59-be71-463e-bc87-bb80f9c5194e, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=10, question_guid=aa740adb-49fd-4008-a896-7353e82d04dd, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=10, question_guid=aa740adb-49fd-4008-a896-7353e82d04dd, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=11, question_guid=502a8e41-1bd1-4d11-847f-faede686f48a, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=11, question_guid=502a8e41-1bd1-4d11-847f-faede686f48a, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=12, question_guid=bdfbfe94-49f8-491d-8b20-e1e03a7d7e24, type=radiogroup, choice_order=1, choice_id=OP1, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=12, question_guid=bdfbfe94-49f8-491d-8b20-e1e03a7d7e24, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if={Question1.7} = 'Yes' and {Question1.8} = 'Yes', is_required=true, read_only=}, {survey_guid=3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8, version_id=1, question_order=7, question_guid=d5862b04-cd56-4a9a-8702-5b78b18390cb, type=radiogroup, choice_order=2, choice_id=OP2, show_other_item=, page_name=1, page_title=, page_description=, visible_if=, is_required=true, read_only=}]

But the service running the same query is returning null


I figured out the issue. I had to use @SpyBean for jdbi as I am defining JDBI as a bean and @IngectMocks for the service I am trying to test.
So, I can use JDBI directly from H2 in-memory and inject it into my service.
@SpringBootTest(classes = DxSurveyManagementApiApp.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SurveyssServiceTest {

    @SpyBean
    Jdbi jdbi;

    @InjectMocks
    SurveyssService surveyssService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void surveyByNameTest() {
        surveyssService.surveyByGuid("3cb00b4a-d00f-40d3-b9b9-902893d852b8");
        // here I can see jdbi is defined in the service and is connecting to H2 db
    }
}

